# How to read file proprties using powershell

Tags: powershell, network-programming, wmi

I have a need to scan a share path and to get the list of files with the following properties.

1. File Path
2. File size
3. Owner information (Created By)
4. Created Date
5. Modified Date

Please help me to get this done.

Comment: What did you already try and where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Chillworld, I am able to get the directoryname, basename, length using the following command "Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Books -Filter *.* -Recurse | Select-Object directoryname, basename, length" But I also in need of owner and created date and modified date.

Comment: Try `get-item (path to some file) | format-list *` which will list available properties...

Comment: This might help...http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/bfe66e89-e6ea-48e8-bcab-6f260493944e/powershell-listing-of-all-files-and-owner-to-csv

Comment: More 'owner' related info here...http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/04/15/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-determine-the-owner-of-a-file.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys will check and post you all here..

Answer (score 1):

This will get you required properties in one object, *Add-Member* adds the extra column for owner extracted from *get-acl*

```
ls \\server\share | % { 
     $o = (get-acl $_.FullName).Owner; 
     $_ | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -name Owner -Value $o; 
     $_ |  select FullName,Length,Owner,CreationTime,LastWriteTime}
```

Comment: Amended the answer, give this one a shot.